# How can I prevent anyone from using a windows admin account remotely?

Tags: windows, security, vpn, remote-access, windows-domain

To describe the current setup: We let our workers remote through a windows VPN Server(RAS). Is there a way to enforce a rule that would prevent any of them from logging into servers/workstations as a domain Administrator, even if they knew the password?

Comment: There is a small IP address pool for all remote users if that is something we can use.

Comment: So to make sure I understand your configuration, you have a VPN which uses Windows authentication, and you want to prevent Administrators from using their elevated accounts to connect to the VPN?  If that isn't what you are trying to do, you need to edit your question, and clarify your question.

Comment: @Ramhound is correct logging into VPN/RAS & logging into server/workstations are two separate things. People usually need to hit/login to VPN before getting into workstations so it'd be safer to block there. Hopefully your VPN allows controlling WHICH users can connect which would be the solution. Maybe provide more info (which Windows Server version, possibly a picture of your RAS setup, etc.)

Comment: @gregg - You raise the exact reason I am confused.  While using your Administrator account to connect to your VPN seems sort of pointless, I understand the reason they want to prevent it, but how you do that (prevent VPN access) and how you prevent an Administrator from having Remote Desktop Access is entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

First of all end users should NEVER know the domain administrator password, if so you should probably change it. Otherwise they should be inherently trustworthy & you shouldn't need to worry about this issue. Domain Administrator & (local) Administrator are automatically part of the Remote Desktop Users local & domain groups & I don't believe you can remove them easily, if at all.

Per [KB323381](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/323381/how-to-allow-remote-users-to-access-your-network-in-windows-server-200) open Active Directory Users and Computers, right-click user, Dial-in (tab), untick Allow Access. The article speaks that a setting on the RAS server controls whether ALL users have access (detailed below) so you may need to change that so only designated users have access:

1. Click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Routing and Remote Access.
2. Double-click Your_Server_Name, and then click Remote Access Policies.
3. Right-click Connections to Microsoft Routing and Remote Access server, and then click Properties.
4. Click Grant remote access permission, and then click OK.

In my 2016 domain forest, right-clicking an AD user & going to Remote Desktop Services Profile I have a checkbox that may help you 'Deny this user permissions to log on to Remote Desktop Session Host server'